# keycode not work in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute some code of js when user press key "enter" or "tab". When I alert keycode then showing correct, but when press key "enter or tab" then not showing any response.
I tried following code.

```
<input id="to" onkeypress="checkemail(event);">

function checkemail(evt)
{
    var keycode =  evt.keyCode? evt.keyCode : evt.charCode;
    //alert(keycode);
    if(keycode=='13'|| keycode=='9')
    {
          //MyCode
        }

}
```

This code is work properly in FireFox, but not showing any result in Google Chrome.
Please tell me any solution if have.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use keyup instead of keypress, keypress is not guaranteed to fire for all keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>

<body>

<input type = "text" id = "to" onkeydown="check(event)">

<script type = text/javascript>

function check(evt)
{
var keycode = evt.keyCode;
alert(keycode);
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

it works in chrome :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using jquery's keydown. it will deal with cross browser issues like this for you

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkemail(evt)
{
    var evt=evt||window.event;
    alert(evt.keyCode);
    if(evt.keyCode==13||evt.keyCode==9)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought my use of keycode in Chrome wasn't working, but it actually does.  I used the enter key to trigger opening a new tab in Chrome.  With recent Chrome updates, the pop-up blocker prevented me from redirecting in a new tab. The target="_blank" wasn't working & had nothing to do with my condition, event.keycode == 13.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It works in chrome you need to type event.keycode/event.key instead of evt.keycode/evt.keycode.also key press doesn't works for these keys you are using